# Android app showing white screen before intent redirect

Tags: android, session, android-intent

On MainActiivity, checking session stored and redirects to SecondActivity. What i expected is show only SecondActivity for session stored user but getting white screen for few second and redirect to SecondActivity. My onCreate method as follow

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        session= new Session(MainActivity.this);
        if(session.getData("auth").equals("true")){
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }else{
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
}
```

Comment: Share `Session` class, does this method `session.getData("auth")` takes time ? Also place this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` just after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: it just a getter

Comment: do you have SecondActivity in manifest?

Comment: @AntonKizema Yes (i already said intent starts after few second then you can assume its in manifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by just disabling window preview in style like below

```
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Spend some hours to find the solution so here is the full description of problem

**Why Window preview?**
Android need some time for load data (on start) from class,resources etc so to overcome android displays a temporary window  called Window preview.
Which gives the user immediate feedback that the app launched and it also gives the app time to initialise itself. When your app is ready to run, the system removes the preview window and displays your app’s windows and views. As a result, none of your Java code is executed when the starting window is displayed.

Comment: where this windowdisablepreview implemented in aosp?

Comment: Because I have a problem that, when white screen is displayed, immediately when user presses home button, it is not redirecting to launcher screen.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView` shouldn't take effect (and any effort for `Activity`) as `finish()` is called earlier inside `onCreate`, but just to be shure add `return` to bracket

what you are seeing is `windowBackground` color, which may be changed in theme of `Activity`

```
// theme for activity, not whole application, will not affect other activities
<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#345678</item>
```

You may also change it by code just before `super.onCreate` call, but for a moment may be visible color from theme (especailly on low end devices) and you don't want this

maybe better approach is new `Activity`, which will be [fully transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android) and redirect straight to proper `Activity`? or if your session restoring is so heavy then use smth without visual representation like `Service`?

be careful with `windowIsTranslucent` flag, because your `Activity` [will loose rotation configuration change calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459841/activity-screen-not-rotating-when-i-rotate-mobile)

Comment: Actually showing one white intent and SecondActivity starts only after few second.(one intent coming foreground animation)

Comment: so set transparent `windowBackground` by XML for `MainActivity` as it resolves session too slow and until then it shouldn't be visible at all

Comment: But that badly affected other activity's background.. any other solution?

Comment: create separated style just for this one `MainActivity` (ans edited). set it in manifest by `<activity android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme">`, keep `AppTheme` for `<Application>` tag and/or all other activities. and if you really need this background then set it just before `setContentView`, when `finish()` isn't called

Comment: problem solved by just disabling window preview,i know you spend lot time.. thank you.